# Decoding euconsent-v2 cookie client side

Tags: javascript, npm, client-side, cookieconsent

I and my team are deploying a new web analytics solution to a client's web site.
The analytics tool is deployed via a tag manager and analytics tracking is executed client side.

The client's using the IAB Transparency and Consent Framework [euconsent-v2 cookie](https://github.com/InteractiveAdvertisingBureau/GDPR-Transparency-and-Consent-Framework/blob/master/TCFv2/IAB%20Tech%20Lab%20-%20Consent%20string%20and%20vendor%20list%20formats%20v2.md#the-core-string) to collect the visitors' consent. The new web analytics tool consent is going to be included there: the analytics tracking shall be enabled for a visitor only if the visitor provides the consent.

So we need to access the euconsent-v2 cookie content and to fetch the analytics consent to enable the analytics tracking. That cookie is encoded.

IAB provides [a tools suite](https://github.com/InteractiveAdvertisingBureau/iabtcf-es) to manage the euconsent-v2 cookie. The suite's [core library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@iabtcf/core) features a decoding method as well, that's what we are after.

Question
The tool suite is available as an NPM library, but we need to implement a decoder that works on the browser side. Is there any way to include that core library client side?